# How to use FitBounds on MapBox Android SDK?

Tags: java, android, mapbox, mapbox-gl

MapBox GL JS contains the FitBounds method to centre on some points, and adjust the zoom to fit the bounds in (https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Map.fitBounds). I can not, however, seem to find any reference to this method in the Android SDK API documentation.

Does anyone know how I can leverage FitBounds(), or an equivalent method of doing so?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

great question. In order to accomplish this you need to create a `LatLngBounds` and then zoom to that location.

so using the latest SDK version, 4.0.0, you'd achieve this with this code:

```
LatLngBounds latLngBounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder()
                    .include(first marker position)
                    .include(second marker position)
                    .build();

CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latLngBounds, 10);
```

You can include as many `LatLng` as you'd like by including them within your bounding box. Hope this helps!

Comment: Great, thanks for the very prompt answer. Appreciated.

Comment: And to give it a little nice effect you can try:
 mapboxMap.easeCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latLngBounds, 50), 5000);

Comment: @cammace What if some part of the map is covered by some Android view?

Comment: How to calculate the zoom level, automatically ?